# JavaScript removeChild(this) from input[type="submit"] onclick breaks future use of form.submit() under Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have come across some strange behaviour, and I'm assuming a bug in Firefox, when removing a input submit element from the DOM from *within* the click event.

The following code reproduces the issue:

```
<form name="test_form">
<input type="submit" value="remove me" onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />
<input type="submit" value="submit normally" />
<input type="button" value="submit via js" onclick="document.test_form.submit();" />
</form>
```

To reproduce:

- Click "remove me"
- Click "submit via js". Note that the form does not get submitted, this is the problem.
- Click "submit normally". Note that the form still gets submitted normally.

It appears that, under Firefox, if you remove a submit button from within the click event it puts the form in an invalid state so that any future calls to `form.submit()` are simply ignored. But it is a JavaScript-specific issue as normal submit buttons within this form still function fine.

To be honest, this is such a simple example of this issue that I was expecting the internet to be awash with other people experiencing it, but so far searching has yealded nothing useful.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so, did you get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My example posted above is the simplest code I could provide which still reproduces the issue; of course the real-world example is much more complex. I'll try to give you some context...

Basically I have an absolutely-positioned DIV, which is functioning as a modal dialog over the top of the html page. It has a "cancel" button which is a input submit element. Clicking this disposes of the dialog DIV and therefore "closes" the dialog, but due to this issue leaves the FORM (which wraps the whole page) unusable.

Comment: why do you need the cancel button to have `type="submit"` if its purpose is not submitting a form? did you try it with `type="button"`

Comment: Yes, and that does fix the issue but I need to have it as type="submit" so it degrades gracefully when javascript is switched off. Ofc, with javascript switched on I could simply replace the submit with a button, but I think we're missing the point here: why does firefox behave this way in the first place, is there anything materially wrong with what I'm doing? Is everyone able to reproduce it reliably and therefore shall I just write it off as a bug in firefox and submit a bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be related to the fact that you're removing the node while processing the event.
This indeed looks like a bug from Firefox.

In the meanwhile, this hack seems to work but delaying the removal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delsubmit(el) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }, 50);

    return false;
}
</script>

<input type="submit" value="remove me" onclick="return delsubmit(this)" />
```

Comment: Very clever, yes this fixes the issue for me and will probably make an acceptable workaround in this case. Good to know that I'm not alone in being able to reproduce it though, just surprised I've not found anyone else reporting it before. Thanks.