# Form will not submit if .remove() is used?

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox, submit

I'm having a spot of bother with either Firefox, jQuery or both. OS is Windows 7, Firefox is version 4.0.1 and jQuery is between 1.5 - 1.6.

Basically I have a form with a `button` element within, to which a click event is attached via jQuery which removes the button's closest parent `div`. This all works wonderfully.

Now the problem comes when you try to submit the form after carrying out the aforementioned action. Chrome, IE, Opera and Safari submit the form fine. Firefox on the other hand refuses to submit the form at all.

I've even tried `$("form").submit();` in Firebug to no avail.

[Here is a test on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CF2Da/1/), simply click the `-` button and then `submit` in Firefox to see what I mean.

Any help on the matter is much appreciated!

**Edit:** I need to be able to submit the form via a Javascript/jQuery event attached to a button *outside* of the `form` element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I've got the final solution for this problem.
I've spend the last couple of days struggling with this strange behavior and finally came accross this thread and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416663/javascript-removechildthis-from-inputtype-submit-onclick-breaks-future-use) which helped me a lot.. =))

The button element has a 'type' attribute which [is set by default to 'submit'](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/button.html) in almost all browsers (except IE).

The problem seems to be related to the fact that we're removing the node while processing the submit event and therefore breaking the submit event of the form...

So adding type="button" to the button element will actually solve this issue.

[Here is a workign jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/L62Da/)

Comment: I confirm that it works. I had exactly the same problem and I was tearing my hair out. Thank you !

Comment: I just want to note, 2 years later, Firefox 24.0, problem persists. Is this bug or what?

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea *why* this is the case, but if you replace:

`<button name="test">-</button>`

with:

`<input type="button" value="-" name="test" />`

and use `$("input[name=test]")` instead of `$("button[name=test]")` then it appears to work.

You can see this working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/CF2Da/21/).

Comment: Can anyone shed any light why this happens?

Comment: Thank you for finding this workaround! I'd also like to hear anyone's opinions as to why Firefox is behaving this way?

Comment: You're welcome. Your problem intrigued me, I spent the last half hour trying to find a way round it. It appears that others have experienced the issue, but there's not much I can find about it via Google.

Answer (score 0):

try using this instead:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

if you put it before the  tag it will submit the form automatically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Firefox/jQuery Submit Bug?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php" id="fform">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" />
            <button name="test">-</button>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This actually doesn't fix the issue, the form still doesn't submit.

Comment: Sorry I never made it clear in my question, but I need to be able to submit the form via Javascript/jQuery and not a submit button. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @davgothic: Using the submit type input doesnt prevent you from submitting the form via js. If calling `$(form).submit()` is the eaxct same as the default submit action invoked when clicking a submit input. IF you actually need to override what happens on submit then just disable the default functionality in your submit handler like `$('form').submit(function(evt){ evt.preventDefault(); /* your override submit code here */});`.

Answer (score 0):

The answere of "paic_citron" is correct but, due you do the "POST" via Ajax you can replace this button:

```
<button name="test">-</button>
```

with hyberlink and some css:

```
<a href="#" class="bnt btn-warning" name="test">
   <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
</a>
```

[Here the jsFiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/Ppmay/)