# Jquery submit not working in firefox but works in chrome

Tags: jquery, forms

i have a form with a number of hidden input fields. i can add and remove these hidden fields from my form. Now my problem is that i want to submit my form through jquery. code for submit is

```
$("#finish").bind('click',function(){
            console.debug("here");
    $(".userInfo").submit();
});
```

where `#finish` is id of the button that submit the form, and `.userInfo` is form class.

Until i don't remove any field from the form (even if i add more hidden fields), the above code works fine and submit the form.

But when i remove one or more of these hidden fields,

```
$(".remo").remove();
```

and then click on finish button, the above code does not submit the form and just prints `here` on console.

Edit : here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CF2Da/1/) from

[Form will not submit if .remove() is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347433/form-will-not-submit-if-remove-is-used)

but my button submit button has already `type=button`

```
<button type="button" id="finish" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Finish</button>
```

Comment: Any error shown? Any demo page? and please show some of the key HTML.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor no error on console. I have added a fiddle link

Comment: If you're just doing a regular form submit, here's a crazy idea, use a regeular submit button without any javascript ?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6347785/188331

Comment: by fiddle link you use `<button name="test">-</button>` so button without `type` is `submit` by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this reference [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6347785/188331), to solve the issue, change `<button>` to `<input>` to avoid the `.remove()` issue.