# Form no longer submit after removing element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a problem similart to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347433/form-will-not-submit-if-remove-is-used)
But I'm using an "a" to submit my form.

Every thing works well without removing elements on the form but when I remove an element using JQuery, the form doesn't reload the page.
The submit() event is fired well and the debug alert message shows but nothing appens.

Here my code sample :

```
<form name="editpage" id="editpage" action="" method="POST">
<div class="module">
    <div class="sortable-handle fi-list ui-sortable-handle"></div>
    <div data-id_table="123" data-id_module="1" data-class="Texte" data-id_zone="1" data-id_navigation="5" class="sortable-delete fi-trash"></div>

    <label for="modules[Texte_123][texte]">Zone de texte</label>
    <textarea rows="20" name="modules[Texte_123][texte]" id="modules[Texte_123][texte]" class="tinymce">                                &lt;p&gt;encore une ! et en FR cette fois !&lt;/p&gt;

    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="fr" name="modules[Texte_123][langue]">

</div>
<div class="module">
    <div class="sortable-handle fi-list ui-sortable-handle"></div>
    <div data-id_table="123" data-id_module="1" data-class="Texte" data-id_zone="1" data-id_navigation="5" class="sortable-delete fi-trash"></div>

    <label for="modules[Texte_124][texte]">Zone de texte</label>
    <textarea rows="20" name="modules[Texte_123][texte]" id="modules[Texte_124][texte]" class="tinymce">                                &lt;p&gt;encore une ! et en FR cette fois !&lt;/p&gt;

    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="fr" name="modules[Texte_124][langue]">

</div>

<a class="button fi-save" href="#" onclick="$('#editpage').submit(); return false;">Save</a>
</form>


<script>
    // Suppression
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").on("click", ".sortable-delete", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = $(this);
    if (confirm('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ça ?')) {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax/pages.php',
                data: {
                    'action': 'del_module',
                    'lg': $langue,
                    'id_navigation': div.data('id_navigation'),
                    'id_zone': div.data('id_zone'),
                    'class': div.data('class'),
                    'id_module': div.data('id_module'),
                    'id_table': div.data('id_table')
                },
                async: false
            }
        ).done(function ($data) {
                if ($data == '1') {
                    div.parents('div.module').fadeOut('normal', function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    alert($data);
                }
            });
    }
});



$('#editpage').submit(function(){
   alert('submit');
});

tinymce.init({selector: '.tinymce'});

});
</script>
```

Thanks for your light !

Pierre M.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: Yep. No error is logged :/

Comment: It seems to work fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/023eue2w/ Is there some other code you have omitted from your example which is interfering with your intended behaviour?

Comment: I just edit my post with the entire code.
Maybe it's TinyMCE... When I don't initialise it, all works fine...